# Combining numeric conditional with like breaks MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with `VARCHAR(255)` columns and a `numeric(15, 2)` column.

If I do this search, it works:

```
select title, cost, pageUrl
from products
where cost between 100 and 125
;
```

and if I do this search query, it works:

```
select title, cost, pageUrl
from products
where title like '%something%'
 or pageUrl like '%something%'
;
```

but when I combine them, it ignores the numeric filter:

```
select title, cost, pageUrl
from products
where cost between 100 and 125
and title like '%something%'
 or pageUrl like '%something%';
```

I've tried a few different variations on the combined query, but I keep having the same problem. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use parentheses:

```
select title, cost, pageUrl
from products
where cost between 100 and 125
      and (title like '%something%' or pageUrl like '%something%');
```

otherwise the numeric filter is combined with the first like predicate and the second like predicate is evaluated separately.

You can check [Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) in the manual if you like.

Answer (score 0):

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. Use parentheses:

```
select title, cost, pageUrl
from products
where cost between 100 and 125
and (title like '%something%' or pageUrl like '%something%');
```

Comment: Thank you (both of you). I will mark this as the solution.